# Calculate the following integral: $\oint \frac{1}{z^{n}-1}dz$ where $\gamma ={|z-1|=\frac{1}{n} , n\in \mathbb{N}}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Calculate the following integral: $\oint \frac{1}{z^{n}-1}dz$ where $\gamma ={|z-1|=\frac{1}{n} ,  n\in \mathbb{N}}$.

I used the following identity: $a^{n}-b^{n}=(a-b)(a^{n-1}b+a^{n-2}b^2...+a^{2}b^{n-2}+ab^{n-1})$ and the formula of the geometric sum to reach the following integral: $\oint \frac{\frac{z-1}{z^n-1}}{z-1}dz$, then I multiplied and divided by $2\pi i $.

My thinking was that this is a difficult Integral, so I decided to use Cauchy's integral formula, but the function $f(z)=\frac{z-1}{z^n-1}$ is undefined for z=1, my question is whether defining a new function that is defined for z=1 could solve this problem?

For example: $g(z)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
 & \\ \frac{z-1}{z^n-1}, if: z\neq 1& \\ 1,   if: z=1\end{matrix}\right.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your function is nothing but $g(z)=\frac 1 {1+z+z^{2}+\cdots z^{n-1}}$. Then $g$ is analytic inside and on the contour  and the given integral is $\int_{\gamma} \frac {g(z)} {z-1}dz$. So you can apply Cauchy's Integral formula.